# Attribute routing unexpected behavior on views outside specific action.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

As an example I have two actions on one controller.
The actions both use attribute routing.

```
[Route("proofCampaign/{campaignId?}", Name ="Route1")]
public ActionResult ProofCampaign(int campaignId){
            //Do stuff
            return View{campaignVM}
            }
[Route("proofOrder/{orderId}", Name ="Route2")]
public ActionResult ProofOrder(int orderId){
            //Do stuff
            return View{orderVM}
            }
```

When I use `@Url.RouteUrl("Route1")` on any view I get the proper url but when I try to use `@Url.RouteUrl("Route2")` on any view I get a null.

However when I go to the actual page/view that Route2 leads to it returns the expected url.

The difference in the above code is the "?" in the route, even though the parameter is not optional. 
Ultimately I want to display the second link on other views as part of a menu.

Why does the route not show up without putting in the optional param indicator?

Comment: Because `orderId` is not optional you need to include it in the Url `@Url.RouteUrl("Route2", new { orderId = xxx )`

Comment: Put it in an answer so I can credit you with it.

Comment: Glad to help. Done as requested. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `orderId` is not optional you need to include it in the Url

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Route2", new { orderId = xxx })
```